# Sun Grid Engine - Submitting job from command line

Tags: cluster-computing, sungridengine

I'd like to submit a job to the Sun Grid Engine using a single command line argument, rather than using a shell script. Can it be done?

Example:

I want to do this, and submit to the batch queue:

```
mkdir empty_directory && cd "empty_directory" && touch "empty_file.txt"
```

Rather than doing this:
dir_script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir empty_directory
cd empty_directory
touch empty_file.txt
```

Then:

```
qsub dir_script.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this all the time, using pipe (`|`):

```
echo "mkdir empty_directory && cd empty_directory && touch empty_file.txt" | qsub [options]
```